# If the spender account holds more than one type of token, how does the transfer in solidity work?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

If an account holds more than one type of token and I want to transfer only a specific token to other addresses using solidity `emit Transfer(_from, _to, _tokens)`, how do I make sure that I'm able to send the right token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token balances are keep in the storage of each token contract. To make transfers you need to send the operation to the token contract.

If a user have REP, GNO and BAT tokens, and he want to transfer GNO tokens he have to send the operations to the GNO contract, there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

`Transfer` event comes from the token contract address that is unique.

Furthermore you call `tranfer()` function against the token contract you wish to send.

Comment: Hi Mikko, thank you for clarifying quickly. That makes sense. However, my client gave me an address that holds different types of tokens and he wants to transfer only a specific token to other addresses using a smart contract. How does it work in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know your client or do not have a business relationship with him, so I cannot comment what he wants or wants not.

Comment: Well, we are not talking about client relationships here. That's irrelevant. Here's my specific question Mikko; if an address contains different ERC20 tokens, is there a way to validate to send only a particular ERC20 token from that address to other addresses using smart contract?